# Extracting text from multiple links and storing independently

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am Data Analyst, know ML and DL, but my web scraping is not good.

I am scraping data. What I am trying to do is the following:

1. using duckduckgo API, I extract all the link for a query, query is like, "what is bitcoin".
2. then, after getting list of links, I want to scrape them one by one and store the text scraped separately, with which I can do my NLP part and etc.

But, my problems are. I am not able to get the best text from these links and sometimes,for few links, I am not able to read HTML from it, it raise getaddress error.

Here is my code.

```
import re, urllib
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import urlopen


query = "litecoin"
site = urlopen("http://duckduckgo.com/html/?q="+query)
data = site.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html5lib")


my_list = soup.find("div", {"id": "links"}).find_all("div", {'class': re.compile('.*web-result*.')})[0:50]

print len(my_list)

(result__snippet, result_url) = ([] for i in range(2))

for i in my_list:         
    try:
        result__snippet.append(i.find("a", {"class": "result__snippet"}).get_text().strip("\n").strip())
    except:
        result__snippet.append(None)
    try:
        result_url.append(i.find("a", {"class": "result__url"}).get_text().strip("\n").strip())
    except:
        result_url.append(None)

print(result_url)
[u'litecoin.org',
 u'litecoin.com',
 u'en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litecoin',
 u'coinmarketcap.com/currencies/litecoin/',
 u'profitconfidential.com/category/cryptocurrency/litecoin/',
 u'fortune.com/2017/12/12/litecoin-bitcoin-price-2018/',
 u'finance.yahoo.com/news/litecoin-everything-need-know-184858...',
 u'cointelegraph.com/tags/litecoin',
 u'worldcoinindex.com/coin/LiteCoin',
 u'litecoin.com/services',
 u'forbes.com/sites/madhvimavadiya/2017/12/12/what-is-l...',
 u'thecollegeinvestor.com/19673/how-to-invest-in-litecoin/',
 u'cnbc.com/2017/12/12/litecoin-price-hits-record-hig...',
 u'markets.businessinsider.com/currencies/ltc-usd',
 u'gdax.com/trade/LTC-USD',
 u'forbes.com/sites/jessedamiani/2017/12/13/5-reasons-w...',
 u'twitter.com/litecoin',
 u'fortune.com/2018/02/14/litecoin-price-cryptocurrency/',
 u'coindesk.com/information/comparing-litecoin-bitcoin/',
 u'fool.com/investing/2017/12/24/5-reasons-litecoin-i...',
 u'profitconfidential.com/cryptocurrency/litecoin/what-is-litecoin/',
 u'litecoin.miningpoolhub.com',
 u'kitco.com/litecoin-price-charts-usd/',
 u'cryptocompare.com/coins/ltc/',
 u'lifewire.com/what-is-litecoin-4151693',
 u'ibtimes.com/litecoin-price-predictions-2018-experts-f...',
 u'livebitcoinnews.com/news/litecoin-news/',
 u'money.cnn.com/2017/12/12/investing/litecoin-price-coinb...',
 u'live.blockcypher.com/ltc/',
 u'reddit.com/r/litecoin/']



from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import Comment

from urllib import urlopen

# Now, I start my scraping.
def tag_visible(element):
    if element.parent.name in ['style', 'script', 'head', 'title', 'meta', '[document]']:
        return False
    if isinstance(element, Comment):
        return False
    return True


def text_from_html(body):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(body, 'html5lib')
    texts = soup.findAll(text=True)
    visible_texts = filter(tag_visible, texts)  
    return u" ".join(t.strip() for t in visible_texts)

try:
    try:
        html = urlopen('www.' + result_url[5]).read()
        print(text_from_html(html))
    except:
        html = urlopen(result_url[1]).read()
        print(text_from_html(html))
except:
    html = urlopen('https://www.' + result_url[5]).read()
    print(text_from_html(html))
```

so, two issues are,for some links, it raises error, and some where it works, the text extracted is meaning less.

Please help!
Please correct me, If I am wrong somewhere in my explanation, scraping first time.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Split your search query and the title of your search result link into keywords. Starting from the  tag search for maximum matches. Then hierarchically enter into the body tag until matches in parent== matches in child. Then pick up the child. Continue process until the matches in parent > matches in every child. Then extract the text in that element. Try using ranks with keywords and see the performance.
If you are ok with information from single source you can use Wikipedia Api. Good Luck!

Comment: I want to create different corpus of text from each link separately, so the pages will be different for each link, so I want just plain text from each ink generalised.

Comment: The above method gives you text which is relevant to your search query in the links which is returned by search engine. If you want summary of each link then you need to do some NLP.

Comment: I dint understood your approach, TBH. I mentioned it is first time I am trying this.